# StreamReader reads null in while loop

Tags: c#, while-loop, streamreader, argumentnullexception

Using this method I am looping through a file removing lines with a `'T'` in them and storing them to a list. At the end of the loop it should exit, however it reads the `null` value and continues to pass it throwing an exception with message...

> System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source'

... at the point where it tries to look for the char.

```cs
public static List<string> GetToolsFromFile()
{
    FileStream FS = new FileStream(OpenFile(), FileMode.Open);
    List<string> list = new List<string>();

    using (StreamReader Sr = new StreamReader(FS))
    {
        char c = 'T';

        while (Sr.ReadLine() != null)
        {
            string line = Sr.ReadLine();
            //MessageBox.Show(line.ToString());
            if (line.Contains(c))
            {
                list.Add(line);
                // MessageBox.Show(line.ToString());
            }
        }

        FS.Close();
    }

    return list;
}
```

The `OpenFile()` is a method using the `OpenFileDialog`.  This was tested and working as it retrieves and displays the contents of the selected file.

Comment: The OpenFile() is a method using that. It opens and reads the file. It shows me every line I need to store. When it comes to the end of the file is when it throws the exception.

Comment: What if the `OpenFile()` returned `null`? You should check that before you proceed.

Comment: JQSOFT if the OpenFile() returned null then how would it read the file I selected? Thanks for the effort but Youssef13 solved it for me.

Comment: @SnoopDog You should not edit the solution into your question.  That's what accepting an answer is for, and now the question doesn't make sense for future readers when it presents code that already works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the ReadLine method **two** times. First time is in the while loop condition, and second time is inside the while body. Let's say your file is 3 lines, here are the calls done to ReadLine method:

1. in loop condition, it reads the first line.
2. in the loop body, it reads the second line and assigns it to the `line` variable.
3. in the loop condition, it reads the third line (which is the last line).
4. in the loop body, it returns null, so your `line` variable is assigned to null then you're calling `Contains` method on a null string. That's what the exception says.

Comment: I have tried removing however the first one using != is a bool. If I use while (line = Sr.ReadLine() != null) I  get an error stating cannot implicitly convert bool to string.

Comment: @SnoopDog, You need to include parenthesis. `while ((line = Sr.ReadLine()) != null)`.

Comment: Adding the extra parenthesis corrected the issue. Thank you for your help

Comment: Dont know why someone down voted it. It fixed the issue correcting it like you stated. Thanks

Comment: +1 for explaining what was wrong and what happens when `ReadLine()` is called like that.  It would be good if this either explained or showed how to fix it, although I suppose the two answers together provide code and an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the corrected code

```
FileStream FS = File.Open(@"c:\path_to_The_File", FileMode.Open);
        List<string> list = new List<string>();

        using (StreamReader Sr = new StreamReader(FS))
        {
            char c = 'T';

            string line = Sr.ReadLine();
            while (line != null)
            {

                //MessageBox.Show(line.ToString());
                if (line.Contains(c))
                {
                    list.Add(line);
                    // MessageBox.Show(line.ToString());
                }

                line = Sr.ReadLine();
            }


            FS.Close();
        }
```